# В чем разница между внутренними структурами коллекции - список и массив?

Tags: java

Допустим у меня есть интерфейс, который реализовывает коллекция(`List`, `Set`).

В чём разница между такими внутренними структурами коллекций:

1. Список
2. Массив с начальным количеством элементов 10 и увеличением количества элементов на 30%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если брать во внимание интерфейсы List и Set, то:
List - допускает дубли
Set - нет
Простая реализация списка - производит перенос данных из одного массива в другой при заполнении.
То есть по сути у Вас пункт 2 является реализацией пункта 1.